# Google Colab does not print for loop output

Tags: printing, google-colaboratory

I was using Google Colab and found that it does not print for loop output. Please see the following screenshot's output, the cell runs but no output is printed. Does anyone have this issue, how to fix it? Thanks.

```
for i in range(5):
    print('{0} out of {1} numbers have been printed'.format(i+1,5),end='\r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why. But if you want the first print is replaced by next print, you can try this code by adding `\r` on the beginning and let end empty.

```
for i in range(5):
  print('\r {0} out of {1} numbers have been printed'.format(i+1,5),end='')
```

and you will get the result

```
5 out of 5 numbers have been printed
```